# Trying to compare a calculation on float values returns false

Tags: php, python, perl

Why it equals allways false?

```
<?php

$a = (0.1+0.2);
print $a."\n";  // results in 0.3
if ( (double)$a == (double)0.3 ) {
     echo "true";
}else{
     echo "not true";
}
echo PHP_EOL;
```

**Perl**

```
perl -e 'if ((0.2+0.1) == 0.3) {print "true\n"; } else { print "false\n"; }'
```

**And now in Python**

```
python -c 'if ((0.2+0.1)!=0.3 ):  print "false" '
```

Comment: See `perl -e 'printf "%.20f %.20f",0.1+0.2,0.3'` for enlightenment.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify a tolerance [also referred to as [epsilon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon)] when comparing floating point values since [it is not an exact representation of the number](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php).

```
function f_cmp(float $a, float $b, float $tol = 0.00001) {
  if( abs($a - $b) < $tol ) { return 0; }
  else { return $a - $b; }
  // return 0 if "equal" within tolerance
  // return < 0 if $a < $b
  // return > 0 if $a > $b
  // for use with PHP functions like usort()
}
```

Or simply:

```
function f_eq(float $a, float $b, float $tol = 0.00001) {
  if( abs($a - $b) < $tol ) { return true; }
  else { return false; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Floating point values have a limited precision. Hence a value might 
>   not have the same string representation after any processing. That also
>   includes writing a floating point value in your script and directly 
>   printing it without any mathematical operations.
>
> If you would like to know more about "floats" and what IEEE
>   754 is, read this:
>   http://www.floating-point-gui.de/

(Standard answer for people who report such bugs at http://bugs.php.net)

Answer (score 1):

Enter this at the Python command line:

```
>>> 0.2 + 0.1
```

You'll probably see:

```
0.30000000000000004
```

0.2 and 0.1 do not have exact representations in binary floating point. See this link for details:

http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html